# Array of Hashrefs: How to access based on hashref "column" values

Tags: perl, dbi, hashref

I have an array of hashrefs built from a database using fethrow_hashref(). The data structure is built like so:

```
while (my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref()) {
    push @lines, $ref;
}
```

I sort the data in the query by program name ascending, so all of the references in the array are still in alphabetical order. Then, I go through each hash and find the value that is numerically equal to a `'1'`. I then take the caolumn name, and store it to compare to the rest of the hashrefs with that program name to ensure they all have a `'1'` in the same column.

```
my $pgm = "";
my $met_lvl = "";
my @devs = ();
my %errors = ();
my $error = "";
foreach my $line_ref (@lines) {
    if ($pgm ne $line_ref->{"PROGRAM"}) {
        if (@devs && $error) {
            # print " Different number metal layers for $pgm: @devs \n";
            $error = "";
        }
        @devs = ();
        $pgm = $line_ref->{"PROGRAM"};
        ($met_lvl) = grep { $line_ref->{$_} == 1 } keys(%$line_ref);
        push @devs, $line_ref->{"DEVICE"};
    } elsif ($pgm eq $line_ref->{"PROGRAM"}) {
        push @devs, $line_ref->{"DEVICE"};
        my ($met_chk ) = grep { $line_ref->{$_} == 1 } keys(%$line_ref);
        if ($met_chk ne $met_lvl) {
            $errors{$line_ref->{"PROGRAM"}} = $line_ref->{"PROGRAM"};
            $error = "YUP";
        }
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to access the hashrefs individually, based on matching column names from the database. How can I access the hashrefs with "TEST" values for "PROGRAM" keys? I used Data::Dumper to provide an example of a few of the hashrefs I'd like to access based on "PROGRAM" value:

```
            'PLM' => undef,
            'SLM' => undef,
            'QLM' => undef,
            'DEVICE' => 'DEV1',
            'TLM' => '1',
            'DLM' => undef,
            'ROUTING' => 'NORMAL',
            'PROGRAM' => 'TEST'
          };
$VAR455 = {
            'PLM' => undef,
            'SLM' => undef,
            'QLM' => undef,
            'DEVICE' => 'DEV2',
            'TLM' => '1',
            'DLM' => undef,
            'ROUTING' => 'NORMAL',
            'PROGRAM' => 'TEST'
          };
$VAR456 = {
            'PLM' => undef,
            'SLM' => undef,
            'QLM' => undef,
            'DEVICE' => 'DEV3',
            'TLM' => '1',
            'DLM' => undef,
            'ROUTING' => 'NON_STANDARD',
            'PROGRAM' => 'EXP'
          };
$VAR457 = {
            'PLM' => undef,
            'SLM' => undef,
            'QLM' => undef,
            'DEVICE' => 'DEV4',
            'TLM' => '1',
            'DLM' => undef,
            'ROUTING' => 'NORMAL',
            'PROGRAM' => 'FINAL'
          };
```

I'd like to be able to access key values for the hashrefs which contain the same program name. I cannot even begin to figure out what type of operation to use for this. I assume `map` is the correct way to do it, but dereferencing the "PROGAM" value for each element (hashref) in the array is beyond the scope of my understanding. I hope I was able to define the problem well enough for you guys to be able to help.

Edit: The impetus for wanting to access hashrefs with the same 'PROGRAM" value is to be able to provide an output of selected values to print to a logfile. So, after I compare and find differences between those hashrefs with the same "PROGRAM" value, I want to access them all again, and print out the desired column values to the lofgile.

Comment: Only select the rows with the particular program you're interested in? Or otherwise do whatever you need with each group in the sql statement? Make the database do the work, not you.

Comment: @Shawn after I get the information I need from the database, I compare the hashrefs based on "PROGRAM" and see if any of the other fields are different. When I find a difference, I save the program name so that I can go back and access the hashes that have the same "PROGRAM" name. I cannot do this on the fly, not that I'm aware of.

Comment: @zdim I added more code, basically the entire program. Hopefully this will clarify what I am trying to do. I can do this same operation while collcting the data from the database, but I'd like to also be able to access the hashrefs with matching values for "PROGRAM" as well.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you need to exrtact subsets of your data (hashrefs) with the same `PROGRAM` name.

Can preprocess your data to build a hash with those names as keys, and arrayrefs (with suitable hashrefs) as values. Then process those groups one at a time.

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';
use Data::Dumper;  # to print complex data below

... populate @lines with hashrefs as in the question or copy-paste a sample

# Build hash: ( TEST => [ hashrefs w/ TEST ], EXP => [ hashrefs w/ EXP ], ... )
my %prog_subset;    
for my $hr (@lines) { 
    push @{ $prog_subset{$hr->{PROGRAM}} }, $hr;
    # Or, using "postfix dereferencing" (stable from v5.24)
    # push $prog_subset{$hr->{PROGRAM}}->@*, $hr;
}

foreach my $prog (keys %prog_subset) { 
    say "\nProcess hashrefs with PROGRAM being $prog";
    foreach my $hr (@{ $prog_subset{$prog} }) {
        say Dumper $hr;
    }
}
```

(See [postfix dereference](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlref#Postfix-Dereference-Syntax))

Now `%prog_subset` contains keys `TEST`, `EXP`, `FINAL` (and whatever other `PROGRAM` names are in data), each having for value an arrayref of all hashrefs which have that `PROGRAM` name.

There are other ways, and there are libraries that can be leveraged, but this should do it.

Comment: I don't think this is going to do what I need. Basically, I'd like to grep for the hashrefs within the AoH that have the same key value for ```PROGRAM```. So, something like ```(@found) = grep { $lines[$_->{PROGRAM}] eq $pgm } @lines;``` That doesn't work though...

Comment: @WetCheerios Hm ... but that's precisely what this does.  More, it builds a hash (`%prog_subset`) with _all_ such key values for `PROGRAM`.  (Did you try it?  Just add a print statement where the commented out line is)  If you want to process just one specific one, and not all, add `next if $prog ne 'TEST`;` and it'll only process hashref for `TEST`.

Comment: I found an example that helped me get what I needed. I did not understand what your snippet was doing with ```%prog_subset``` so I did not modify the code to include it. Please see my answer above. Thanks again for the help sir, or madam.

Comment: @WetCheerios Well, great you got it :).  But I 'd like to clarify what this does, since it's exactly what you need. That hash `%prog_subset` is this: `( TEST => [ hashrefs with PROGRAM equal to TEST ],  EXP => [ hashrefs with PROGRAM equal to EXP ], ... etc );`.  Those `[...]` are an array reference.  So `Sprog_subset{$pgm}` is an array reference with all hashrefs that have `PROGRAM` equal to `$pgm`.  You can see them by `for my $hr (@{ $prog_subset{$pgm} }) { say Dumper $hr };`.

Comment: @WetCheerios Edited, so now you can copy-paste this code as a separate program, and copy-paste into it some of that `@lines` array at the beginning and run it to see how it works.   (Just tested it.)

Comment: Ah, yes. I see it now. That is clever. Thank you, and I look forward to your help with future questions I will, undoubtedly, raise with the community.

Comment: @WetCheerios You're most welcome :).  Please ask away :)  I'm always happy to try to help out

Answer (score 0):

OK! I found an example of this with the google machine. I replaced `@lines = ();` with `$lines = [];`. This allowed me to change the grep statement to `(@found) = grep { $pgm eq $_->{PROGRAM} } @$lines;`. Now the returned array is a list of the hashrefs that share the program name I'm looking for. Thanks for the help @zdim!